# OpenGL acceleration stopped working after upgrading to Wheezy

Tags: upgrade, debian, opengl

After upgrading recently from Squeeze to Wheezy, my 3D acceleration suddenly stopped working. I'm using IBM Thinkpad T60 with ATI M52 [Mobility Radeon X1300].

I found in Xorg.0.log:

```
[ 48286.173] (EE) AIGLX error: r300 does not export required DRI extension
[ 48286.174] (EE) AIGLX: reverting to software rendering
[ 48286.180] (II) AIGLX: Loaded and initialized swrast
[ 48286.180] (II) GLX: Initialized DRISWRAST GL provider for screen 0
```

But I have no clue how to solve the problem.

*Update:* Possibly related: http://bugs.debian.org/639621